# Can the .net reportviewer allow Copy Paste?

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am working on SSRS reports which is eventually hosted in SharePoint, 
we show/run the reports in Winform application using ReportViewer 10.0  control.

Is it possible to copy data from ReportViewer to clipboard?

Note: It does allow on SharePoint when we browse from FF,IE etc..

Comment: Is this kind of solution for you?http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17002/Two-simple-workarounds-for-the-ReportViewer-proble

In our application we only use report viewer to generate pdf document for us.

Comment: bit kind of hack though, I am looking solution which can be done on front-end(winform) side rather than in actual reports. tx for yuor interest.